# makefile rule for lazy c++

Tags: makefile, lazy-c++

I want to include a rule in my makefile for converting my lazy c++ `.lzz` files into their respective `.h` and `.cpp` files.

It seems to me to be a slightly unusual case where two files depend on one, and I'm not confident that I'll be able to get the dependencies set up correctly.

```
# something like...
%.cpp %.h : %.lzz
    lzz $<
```

Anyone have a rule that works well?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work? If not, what errors (if any) do you get?

Answer (score 2):

That looks right to me.

From the make info pages:

> A rule with multiple targets is equivalent to writing many rules, each with one target, and all identical aside from that.  The same commands apply to all the targets, but their effects may vary because you can substitute the actual target name into the command using `$@'.  The rule contributes the same prerequisites to all the targets also.

Comment: From [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Intro): Pattern rules may have more than one target. Unlike normal rules, this does not act as many different rules with the same prerequisites and recipe. If a pattern rule has multiple targets, make knows that the rule's recipe is responsible for making all of the targets. The recipe is executed only once to make all the targets.